# How to convert 3D point in OpenCV to Eigen representation?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, eigen

What is the best way to convert a 3D point (`cv::Point3`) in OpenCV to Eigen representation?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best representation in Eigen is `Vector3d`, such as:

```
cv::Point3d p(1,2,3);
Eigen::Vector3d point(p.x, p.y, p.z);
```